# What is the difference between "information", "data", "knowledge", "science"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

I know it may be dumb but what is the difference between the following words?

- *information*
- *data*
- *knowledge*
- *science*

Especially the difference between *data* and *information*?
I know it but cannot explain it well to my teacher.

Comment: I think these differences are all General Reference. The one OP is most concerned about is frequently referenced in print - ["convert data into information"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22convert+data+into+information%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), so even if that one is more subtle than the others, it's easy to find examples making the distinction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: These are General Reference only in the minds of educated native speakers. Dictionaries don't spell it out. The definitions of all of these are vague enough that they sound like synonyms, but no native speaker would use them interchangeably.

Comment: @Mitch: I never suggested any of the differences would be obvious by comparing dictionary entries - just that *"convert/turn data into information"* is a common sequence of words. Looking at a few instances would make even that one fairly obvious, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are slight differences.

Basically, data is gained through experiments and studies. Information is gained through analysis of this data. Knowledge is then gained from the understanding of the information available. Science is all about this process.

Answer (score 1):

**Data** are isolated facts without any particular context or interpretation.

**Knowledge** is an organized and contextualized statement of what we already know.

**Information** is new knowledge that was unknown previously.  Note that what is information to one person may be knowledge to someone else.

**Science** is a process by which one tries to generate `information` about how the world works by creating models that account for current `knowledge` and then using experimentation to obtain `data` that leads to new `information`.  The new information may either be consistent with the initial model or it may refute the model, leading to the need to refine or replace the model.

Answer (score 0):

Knowledge is what we know. 
Data is/are the facts of the World.
Information allows us to expand our knowledge beyond the range of our senses. We can capture data in information, then move it about so that other people can access it at different times.

Comment: 'Capture'? I'd say information *structures* data, provides it a meaningful form.